# Is there a way to cache the video in the sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, cache

In the sequence editor, when you load an image strip, it can be slow.  You have to play the video twice to "cache" the video.  Is there a way i can just click a button to do this, like how you bake a smoke simulation?

Comment: also, i added a gausian blur between to strips, and now the video is **_super_** slow.

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/video_editing/sequencer/properties/proxy_cache.html

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't find an answer.  The feature might not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the timeline playback set *Sync* to *Play Every Frame*. This will cache it.

[image]